# evaluate a variable in mathjax

Tags: r-markdown, mathjax

When I render an Rmd report with MathJax formulas, I often I have numeric values saved as variables that I would like to evaluate within MathJax.

```
MY_VAR <- 42
```

$$outcome_i = {MY_VAR} + \beta_1 X_1$$

I would like MY_VAR to be evaluated so that the output looks like [image], but I am not sure how to trigger the evaluation of the `MY_VAR` variable within MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following syntax:

Rcode chunk:

````
```{r}
A <- 42
```
````

and after that use `r yourRcode ` inline expression inside the mathjax statement.

```
$outcome_i = `r A` + \beta_1 X_1$
```

this works with single `$` sign.

or as a centered block fenced with `$$ ...$$` ( double `$$`)

Comment: This did not work for me. I have updated the post to show what \`r \` produced for me.

Comment: I don't see any update.  Maybe it didn't get saved?

Comment: BTW, the suggested solution worked for me.